# how to get the value in edittxt android and put it in a URL

Tags: android

```
private Button btnLogin;
private EditText txtPub;
private EditText txtPriv;
final Context context = this;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginfirst);

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtPub = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPublic);
    txtPriv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPrivate);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

in WebViewActivity.class

```
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://url.com/txtpub+txtprive");

}
```

how can I get the value of edittxt txtpub and txtpriv and put in webviewactivity class in the url above? I wanted to put the value of txtpub and txtpriv in the url. help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Button btnLogin;
private EditText txtPub;
private EditText txtPriv;
final Context context = this;
String a;
String b;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.loginfirst);

btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
txtPub = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPublic);
txtPriv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPrivate);

a=txtPub.getText();
b=txtPriv.getText();
}



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
Bundle bundleObj = new Bundle();

        bundleObj.putString("first", a);
        bundleObj.putString("sec", b);

        intent.putExtras(bundleObj);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

in WebViewActivity.class

```
private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String a=extras.getString("first");
String b=extras.getString("sec");

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://url.com/" + a + b);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the values using extras to the other activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
 intent.putExtras("txtpub",txtpub.getText().toString());
 intent.putExtras("txtpriv",txtpriv.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);

}
```

and in the other activity get the values from the extras in the webviewactivity class using

```
String txtpub = getIntent().getStringExtra("txtpub");
 String txtpriv= getIntent().getStringExtra("txtpriv");
```

and pass it to the url like

```
webView.loadUrl("http://url.com/"+txtpub+txtprive);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from edit text in some button click or anything else just do this :

```
txtPub.getText().toString();
```

this will return the value from your edit text.
As I can see your webview is in another activity, so you can send this value to your webview activity in this way :

```
intent.putExtra("my_url", txtPub.getText().toString());
```

and in your webview activity you can get that value as :

```
String my_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("my_url", null);
```

and load the value in your webview. That's all : )

Answer (score 0):

in your onClick, you can add the values into the intent.

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     intent.putExtra("txtPub", txtPub.getText().toString();
     intent.putExtra("txtPriv", txtPriv.getText().toString();
 }
```

Then, in your webviewActivity you can use

```
 Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras();
 String txtPub = b.getString("txtPub");
 String txtPriv = b.getString("txtPriv")
```